# Union all table for result

Tags: php, mysql

I just want to get result in my 3 table. First it will sum qty of each itemcode. Then output the result based on my formula below.

```
SUM(table 1)
itemcode   qty   date
001        20   06-17
002        20   06-17
001        10   06-18


+(add) of

SUM(table 2)
itemcode   qty  date
001        10   06-17
002        40   06-17
001        5    06-18

-(subtract) of 

table 3
itemcode   qty date
001        5   06-17
002        5   06-17
002        5   06-18
```

Result :

```
itemcode   qty
001        40
002        50
```

Comment: Unclear what you saying ? your result doesn't make sense at all that how you get that result based on table 1 , 2, 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the below query

```
select t.itemcode as itemcode,sum(t.qty) as qty
from ( 
select itemcode,qty from table1
union all
select itemcode,qty from table2
union all
select itemcode,(qty * -1) from table3) as t
group by t.itemcode
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :) http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce1d25/1/0

```
select TsumaTotal.itemcode, suma-resta from
(select Tsuma.itemcode,SUM(Tsuma.suma) as suma from
(select tb1.itemcode, SUM(tb1.qty) as suma from Table1 as tb1 group by tb1.itemcode
UNION
select tb2.itemcode, SUM(tb2.qty) as suma from Table2 as tb2 group by tb2.itemcode) as Tsuma
group by Tsuma.itemcode) as TsumaTotal right join 
(select tb1.itemcode, SUM(tb1.qty) as resta from Table3 as tb1 group by tb1.itemcode) as Tresta
on TsumaTotal.itemcode = Tresta.itemcode;
```

[image]

Comment: No. Don't do it this way

Comment: true, the Andrews B Anthony way is better